# jQuery - replace text formatted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<pre class="article">
    aaa aaa aaabbb
</pre>
```

```
(function ($) {
    var test = $("pre.article");
    test.html(test.text().replace(/aaa/g, '<span class="aaa">111</span>'));
});
})(jQuery)
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/sisi_sajah/f8am0sw1/1/)

**how to keep the results into:  111 111 aaabbb**
*please help me ....*

Comment: Use word boundaries `/\baaa\b/g`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you catch also the space after the `aaa`:

```js
$(function() {
  var test = $("pre.article");
  test.html(test.text()
            .replace(/aaa /g, '<span class="aaa">111</span> '));
})
```

```css
.aaa{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre class="article">
aaa aaa aaabbb
</pre>
```

(and inside the replacement - add that space back)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a \s to the end of the search text to only look for that pattern with any white space character after the pattern.

`.replace(/aaa\s/g, '<span class="aaa">111</span>')`

To keep the space without having to add it back in use \b, which anchors to the end of a word.

`.replace(/aaa\b/g, '<span class="aaa">111</span>')`

You can try different expressions on a string with a regex tester like [regex101](http://regex101.com)

Answer (score 0):

Line 5 of your JavaScript you want a space after aaa in your replace and 111 in your span:

```
.replace(/aaa /g, '<span class="aaa">111 </span>'));
```